Finding variables in a parametric equation given its cartesian
I am tackling some algebra exercises that I found on a worksheet on the internet (so I do not have access to chance to contact the professor who prepared them and made them available on his free-access website) in preparation for my first year of university after a period of academic slumber.
This exercise, in particular, gives a cartesian equation of a line $r$ and a parametric one. Now the parametric one features two variables $a, b$ and asks for what values of $a, b$ the parametric equation is the parametric equivalent of the cartesian equation of the line $r$.
For example:
$r: y = 2x$
and
$(a + t, bt)$
Now in this case, I took two points $A$ and $B$ belonging to $r$. Recalling the generic parametric equation of a line given two points $A$ and $B$ I get:
$
    A = (1, 2), B = (2, 4)$
$
    r: A + t(B - A) = (1, 2) + t(1, 2) = (1, 2) + (t, 2t) = (1 + t, 2 + 2t)$
All I have to do now is set up a double equivalence:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
1 + t = a + t \\
2 + 2t = bt   
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and I get:
$
    a = 1$
$
    b = \frac{(2 + 2t)}{t}$
So far, so good. The problem arises a couple of exercises down the line where for a line $r$ the parametric equation with its two variables $a, b$ is in the form:
$(a + bt, 2 - 5t)$
I tried approach it the same way I did with the first example but I ended up going in circles around equations that lead me to nowhere. I tried to rewrite the parametric equation in some other way but that failed too.
Am I missing something here? Is there something I can do to go past this? Thanks everyone for your help and patience.

Your method for the first question is incorrect. $b$ has to be a constant, so it cannot depend on $t$. The problem is that a line can have more than one parametric equation, so you can't just take two parametric equations for the same line and assume that the terms in them must be equal. For example, the parametric equation $(t, t+2)$ passes through $(0,2)$ diagonally at time $0$, and the equation $(t+3, t+5)$ passes through the point $(0,2)$ diagonally at time $-3$. The issue is there are multiple choices of which time the parametric equation hits a point at, giving different equations.

I'm confused about what the Cartesian equation is meant to be for question 1. You say it is $y=2$, but the point $(2,4)$ is not on that line.

Just a suggestion: $0$ can make your life so much easier. $(0,0)$ is also a point on your line, and if you'd taken it as one of your two points, the calculations would have been simpler. More generally, if you need to pick values for something, you would be wise to pick either $0$, or a number which will make some important expression $0$.

Your biggest mistake was to think there is only one parametric equation for the line. $P(t) = A + t(B - A)$ is indeed a parametric equation for the line. For each value of $t, P(t)$ will be a point on the line, and for every point $E$ on the line, there is some $t$ with $P(t) = E$. Note that $P(0) = A$, and $P(1) = B$.
But $A$ and $B$ are just two arbitrary points on the line, which has uncountably many points on it. If $C$ and $D$ are two other points on the line, then we can do the same thing with them: $\bar P(t) = C + t(D-C)$. This is also a parametric equation for the same line. Note that $\bar P(0) = C$ and $\bar P(1) = D$, so $P$ and $\bar P$ are different parametrizations of the same line.
In your problem, you are given a particular parametrization $Q(t) = (a+t,bt)$, and are asked to find the values of $a,b$ that make it a parametrization of $r$. You took two points on the line and then just assumed that the arbitrary parametrization $P(t)$ you got from them would be the exact same as $Q(t)$. This would require you to be extremely lucky in the points $A, B$ that you picked.
Picking $A = (1,2), B = (2,4)$ was okay. But instead of working up a parametrization from them, you should have considered how they fit into the parametrization you already have. There is some value $t$ with $Q(t) = A$, and some value $s$ with $Q(s) = B$. This gives you two vector equations:
$$(a + t, bt) = (1,2)\\(a + s, bs) = (2,4)$$
which is four numeric equations:
$$\begin{align}a + t &= 1\\bt &= 2\\a+s &= 2\\bs &= 4\end{align}$$
You can solve this system of four equations for its four unknown values $a, b, t, s$, though you only need $a,b$. This is not hard to do. $t = 1 - a, s = 2 - a$, so substitute those into the other two equations:
$$b(1-a) = b-ab = 2\\b(2-a) = 2b-ab = 4$$
Subtracting the first equation from the second gives $b=2$, which with $bt = 2$ gives $t = 1$, $a + 1 = 1$ and $a = 0$. $a = 0, b = 2$ is your answer.
Now per my point in a comment: You could have chosen $(0,0)$ and $(1,2)$ as your points on $r$ instead. Then your set of equations would have been $$\begin{align}a + t &= 0\\bt &= 0\\a+s &= 1\\bs &= 2\end{align}$$
Assuming $b \ne 0$, this immediately implies $t = 0$, so $a = 0$, and then $s = 1$, so $b = 2$. So much easier. Zero - let it be your hero.
